# Pregunta sobre el metodo estatico Busqueda Binaria ( Arrays.binarySearch ) java

Tags: java

directo al grano, estoy leyendo el libro de “Como programar en java 10ed Deitel & Deitel”, voy en un capitulo donde abordan y hablan sobre la clase Arrays y los métodos estáticos como binarySearch.

En la teoría al respecto de éste método, entiendo que binarySearch retorna el índice del valor a buscar; de lo contrario devuelve un valor negativo, donde ese valor negativo depende del ultimo índice y le resta -1. Ejemplo:

int[] arregloEjemplo = {10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}

si buscáramos un numero como “30”, Arrays.binarySearch(arregloEjemplo, 30) retorna  “-10 = -9 -1″ me gustaría que alguien me confirmara si lo que entiendo está bien.

Ahora bien, cito textualmente…”Al restar 1 al punto de inserción se garantiza que el método binarySearch devuelva valores positivos (>= 0) sí, y sólo si se encuentra la clave. Este valor de retorno es útil para insertar elementos en un arreglo ordenado.”

No entiendo como restar 1 al punto de inserción garantice que el método devuelva valores positivos.

Answer (score 0):

Si buscas 5, el punto de inserción es 0 (primera posición).

Por supuesto -0 = 0, así que si solo usarás el negativo del punto de inserción no sabrías si es que 5 no está y es más pequeño que el primer elemento, o si es el primer elemento (índice 0).

Añadiendo -1 ya no hay confusión posible.

Answer (score 0):

Está algo confuso lo que citas. Pero te pongo un ejemplo para ver si entiendes mejor.

El método que mencionas te retorna 0 o positivo si encuentra el valor en el arreglo. Y si no lo encuentra te retorna un valor derivado de esta fórmula
  retorno = -(puntoDeInserción) -1;

¿para qué?

Te retorna ese dato para que sepas en que posición tendrías que insertar el número para que la lista "siga ordenada" (sorted).

Citando tu ejemplo:

int posicion = Arrays.binarySearch(arregloEjemplo, 30);

posicion = -10   =  -(punto de insercion) -1;

-10 = -puntoDeInsercion  -1

-10 + 1 = -puntoDeInsercion -1 +1 //aqui sumamos uno a cada lado de la ecuación

-9 = -puntoDeInsercion;

puntoDeInsercion = 9;  //multiplicando ambos lados por -1;

Dicho esto, con el valor retornado puedes saber si lo encontró o no, y también puedes saber en que posición insertarlo para mantener el arreglo ordenado.

```
int position = Arrays.binarySearch(arregloEjempo, numero);

if (position >=0 ) {
   System.out.println("encontrado en posicion "+position);
}
else {
  System.out.println("no econtró, pero lo puedo insertar en posición "(-(position+1)));
}
```